# BlockingQueue with slow producer and fast consumers

Tags: java, multithreading, queue

I'm writing a Java command line application that scrapes a website and downloads video files. The video files range in size from a few megs to 20 GB or more. This means downloading a file can take as little as a few seconds to as much as a few hours. I've decided to implement a produce/consumer pattern to handle the scraping and downloading of files. A producer thread scrapes the site and retrieves the links to the video files and puts those links into an object and puts that object into an unbounded blocking queue. There are N consumer threads that handle the download. They retrieve the objects containing the URLs from the blocking queue and each thread downloads the file. The object that the producer puts on the queue contains the URL along with some other information that the consumer will need to save the file to the correct location in local storage. Before a file is downloaded, the consumer thread first checks if the file already exists in local storage. If the file exists, the download is skipped and the next object is pulled from the queue. If a consumer experiences a problem while downloading a file (connection reset, etc.), the consumer puts the object containing the URL into a separate queue for failed requests and sleeps for 15 minutes. This allows the application to deal with temporary network interruptions. While the producer is active, it checks the failed URLs queue and removes those URLs from that queue and puts them back into the main queue.

After implementing this initial design, I quickly realized that I had a problem. Because I'm using a blocking queue and the worker threads are polling without a timeout, once the producer was finished, it couldn't just complete its execution because it needed to hang around to put failed URLs back into the queue. My first attempt at a solution was to remove the second "failure" queue and have workers put failed URLs back into the main queue. This meant that the application now had N consumers and N + 1 producers. This approach would allow the main producer thread to just exit when it was finished because it didn't have to worry about putting failed requests back into the queue. Once that problem was solved, there was still another problem. The problem of notifying the worker threads that they could exit once the queue was empty. A blocking queue has no mechanism for the producer to signal that it won't be putting more data to the queue. I thought about having the consumers poll the queue with a timeout and have the primary producer set some sort of flag when it exits. When a consumer times out, it checks the flag. If the flag is set, the consumer exits, if not set, it polls the queue again. While this approach will work, I don't like the design. I don't like the idea of having threads sitting around unnecessarily and I hate even more the use of a magic flag. The only interaction between producer and consumers should be via the queue. The consumers have no knowledge of the producer and checking a magic flag breaks that principle.

I ditched the blocking queue and decided to use a regular non-blocking queue. To prevent the worker threads from exiting as soon as they started, I used a [CyclicBarrier](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html). When a worker thread starts, it waits at the barrier before polling the queue. Meanwhile, the producer thread was coded to lower the barrier once the queue contained 10 x N URLs. Once the barrier was lowered, the worker threads would begin processing the Queue. This approach quickly failed because in some cases the consumers would consume the queue faster than the producer could replenish it. This happens in cases where a large number of files are already stored on disk so the consumers don't need to download anything. Once the queue was empty, the consumers exited, even though the producer was still scraping the site looking for URLs.

This tells me that I need to use a blocking queue. I'm continuing to try to find a clean, elegant solution that doesn't depend on timeouts and magic flags. I would love to hear your approach to solving this problem given the requirements.

UPDATE:
I finally settled on a solution based on comments made by user Martin James. Since these were comments and not an answer, there isn't an answer for me to accept. If Martin summarizes his comments into an answer, I'll accept it. Now here's the solution.

When the producer thread completes, it places N objects into the queue that contain `null` as the value for the URL. I updated the consumer thread to check for a `null` URL when they pull an object from the queue. If the URL is `null`, the consumer exits. This approach solves the notification to consumers that the producer is complete. However, it doesn't solve the problem of consumers putting URLs into the queue after the producer has exited. To solve that problem, I switched to a priority blocking queue. I made the object that gets put into the queue a [Comparable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) and the `compareTo` logic was coded such that objects with `null` values for the URL will always be last in the queue. So when the producer exits and it places the terminating objects in the queue, if/when a consumer places an object back into the queue, those objects will always be ahead of the terminating objects.

Thanks all for the comments and feedback. Very much appreciated.

Comment: 'once the producer was finished, it couldn't just complete its execution because it needed to hang around to put failed URLs back into the queue'....why is that a problem?

Comment: 'The problem of notifying the worker threads that they could exit once the queue was empty'..is that necessary?

Comment: 'blocking queue has no mechanism for the producer to signal that it won't be putting more data to the queue'.  That's easy, if you really need to do it - queue up a null reference instead of a valid URL object and have the work threads check the dequeued reference for null and, if it is, requeue the null and terminate.  Pretty soon after posting the null, all your work threads will have got the null and be gone:)

Comment: Yes, there is still the issue of how the producer could determine when the last download has been successfully downloaded, ie. there can be no more download attempts to retry:(

Comment: Maybe a priority queue with the killer-null as lowest priority?  That would seem to work?

Comment: My solution would be to use as much flags and things as possible. Right now you dont have a solution that works. As for calling for an "elegant" solution that is a qualitative statement so that leads me NOWHERE!!

Comment: Thinking more about it, it seems to me that, if you don't need notification of the completion of all downloads, all that would be needed is for the work threads to keep a private flag that indicates if it just queued up a retry request.  If it gets a null, (or other termination request), it requeues the termination request but only terminates itself if it has not just requeued a retry.  That ensures that there will alwsys be a thread to handle any last retries:)

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be to use framework with back-pressure mechanism support, for example [vert.x reactive streams](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-reactive-streams/java/).

Good examples of systems handling back-pressure built on vert.x can be found in the book [vert.x in action](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-reactive-streams/java/)

Answer (score 0):

`ExecutorService` in Java, for example, is a producer-consumer model with a series of worker threads trying to fetch tasks from a work queue. I might close the thread pool by `ExecutorService#shutdownNow`, this method will set the thread pool state to `STOP` and interrupt each worker. Take a look at `shutdownNow` method and worker's run method(I removed the irrelevant code):

```
  public List<Runnable> shutdownNow() {
            advanceRunState(STOP);
            interruptWorkers();
  }
```

```
final void runWorker(Worker w) {
        try {
            while (task != null || (task = getTask()) != null) {
                // ...
            }
        } 
    }
```

```
 private Runnable getTask() {
        boolean timedOut = false; // Did the last poll() time out?
        for (;;) {
            // ...
            // Check if queue empty only if necessary.
            if (rs >= SHUTDOWN && (rs >= STOP || workQueue.isEmpty())) {
                decrementWorkerCount();
                return null;
            }
            try {
                Runnable r = timed ?
                    workQueue.poll(keepAliveTime, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS) :
                    workQueue.take();
                if (r != null)
                    return r;
                timedOut = true;
            } 
        }
    }
```

I think this is an example of using Flag & interrupt to stop consumers. I don't think it's inelegant.

Comment: This approach requires the thread to poll the queue with a timeout. For this application, how often the producer places a new object in the queue is indeterminate. It could be as little as a few milliseconds to as much as a few minutes. This means choosing a suitable timeout for the consumers is almost impossible. The goal is to prevent the consumer threads from needlessly consuming CPU time as well as needlessly blocking. The consumer threads should only block while the producer is active. If the producer has exited, the consumers should exit once the queue is empty.